# Need regex for adding String before special character

Tags: regex

I have a tweet and i need to match the #regex and add

```
 <a href=twitter.com/#!/search/%23regex>#regex</a>
```

i use the following one to add anchors to https

```
"(?:https?|ftps?)://[\\w/%.-]+", "<a href='$0'>$0</a>"
```

may be some modifications to it might work?

Comment: #regex is an example i need to look for # and then do the operation on the next word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what language you are using, but I would try this:

```
"#\\w+", "<a href='twitter.com/#!/search/%23$0'>$0</a>"
```

That should capture any sequence of `#` followed by a series of alphanumeric characters.

Comment: how to remove the # in the second $0?

Comment: Use a positive lookbehind for the `#` so that it is used for the match but not captured: `"(?<=#)\\w+"`. More info here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html